# Convert very large number stored as string into number

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to store a value with a large number of decimals in a float variable, but I get this error.

> print long('37.7745985956747') Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ValueError: invalid literal for
>   long() with base 10: '37.7745985956747'

I have reviewed all of the other suggested questions here, but none seem to solve my problem and they all mention an additional non-numerical character being present in the string.

I've reviewed both `Decimal` and `Float` and it seems that `float` will truncate the number and `Decimal` throws an error:

```
>>> a = '-122.425891675136'
>>> print float(a)
-122.425891675
>>> from decimal import *
>>> print decimal(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'decimal' is not defined
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should post your failed attempt at `Decimal`, since that's what you want.

Comment: @roippi Actually, Decimal is not exactly what I want. I've also tried `float`, but it will truncate the number.

Comment: Sorry, but then you need `Decimal`.  `float` can and will not give you arbitrary precision.  That is what `Decimal` is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to its `help()`, `long()` converts a number or string to a long integer. `'37.7745985956747'` doesn't represent an integer, so `long()` can't parse it. If you do want a `long()` from that, you'll have to do `long(float('37.7745985956747'))`, which will produce `37L`.

Comment: I've tried `float` too, but it truncates the number. Any suggestions to avoid truncation?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu - `float()` does not truncate the number. `long()` does. If you want to keep the decimal portion, you shouldn't be using `long()` at all.

Comment: You were right, I was using Decimal, but not using the correct case when trying to make the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

`long` can't be used to parse a string representing a number with a decimal point. What it could be confusing is that it can be used to convert a float number to a long like `long(37.7)`.

So you need to convert your number to float first and then truncate it with `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You want a [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

As the docs say,

> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly.

Also,

> Unlike hardware based binary floating point, the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem.

As you can see, it works for your specified input:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('37.7745985956747')
Decimal('37.7745985956747')
```

Though, at least on my end, so does `float`, FWIW:

```
>>> float('37.7745985956747')
37.7745985956747
```

You definitely don't want [`long`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#long), since those are "long **integer** objects". They won't store decimals at all.